# How to split an string using "\" and what is the best option to split

Tags: php

I am trying to split this string and get only the word "Test"

```
App\Http\Controllers\TestController
```

What I want to do is to "explode" using "\" but I think that that character escapes the quotes. How can I use that character?

I got a solution but using more lines of code than necessary. I know that there should be a better solution.

```
 $path = "App\Http\Controllers\TestController";
 $arrayStr = explode("\Test", $path);
 $word = explode('Controllers', $arrayStr[1]);
 $correctWord = implode($word);
 $correctWord = substr($correctWord, 1);
```

I am new using php, so any advice is more than wellcome.

edit: I forgot to specify that I want to get whatever word comes before Controller and after the last .

Thank you!

Comment: Probably a dupe. Probably get a bunch of answers using regex. I'd just use string functions. What is the logic? Everything between last backslash and word 'Controller'?

Comment: I forgot to specify that. I want to get whatever word comes before Controller.

Comment: @ficuscr `$correctWord = current(explode('Controller', end(explode("\\", $path))));` ?

Comment: So many options! I was thinking tokenize, strip out 'Controller'. I come from the days of `ereg` and I think that just makes me gravitate towards the plethora of native string functions PHP offers. Maybe go with the `preg` approach if just that much more readable than string alternatives.

Comment: *strip out 'Controller'.*  +1 :)

Comment: `str_replace('Controller', '', substr($uri, strrpos($uri, '\\') + 1));` avoiding having to get into arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex to find a word between the last backslash and the word 'Controller'

```
$path = "App\\Http\\Controllers\\TestController";
if( preg_match('~\\\\([^\\\\]+)Controller~', $path, $m) ) {
    echo $m[1];
}
else {
    echo 'Not found';
}
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a229ed38a34833cc2b896505022ef7aa38417599)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you were having with explode is that the backslash escapes the closing quote of the delimiter string. So `$path_segments = explode("\", $path);` is a syntax error.

Fortunately, you can also escape the escape character. (Works the same way with single or double quotes.)

```
$segments = explode('\\', $path);
```

Then get your controller from the last piece using `substr`.

```
$controller = substr(end($segments), 0, -10);
```

(The -10 refers to the length of "Controller".)

Comment: weird, this was supposed to be an edit of my other answer. Not sure how I ended up posting it as a second answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a regex to achieve this; you can do it in a single line with **[`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)**:

```
$path = "App\Http\Controllers\TestController";
preg_match('/Test/', $path, $correctWord); // 'test'
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/t3g)**.